# Split strings in list when one element is 'nan'

Tags: string, list, date, split, nan

I have a long list with dates on the form ["2019-11-01 00:15:00+01", "2019-11-01 00:30:00+01", "2019-11-01 00:45:00+01" ... and so on]. I would like to go through the list and remove the "00:15:00+01"-part. After help from this forum, I tried the following:

```
  date_time_list =["2019-11-01 00:15:00+01", "2019-11-01 00:30:00+01", "2019- 
  11-01 00:45:00+01"]
  date_list = []

  for elem in date_time_list:
     date,time = elem.split()
     date_list.append(date)
  print(date_list)
```

However, one of my cells contains a 'nan' and I get the error message: ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected 2, got 1).
Does anyone know how to solve this problem *without deleting the 'nan'-cell*?
Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

Try the below

```
fields = elem.split()
if len(fields) == 2:
   date_list.append(fields[0])
```

Or (if `elem` is `None`)

```
  for elem in date_time_list:
     if elem is not None:
         date,time = elem.split()
         date_list.append(date)
```